# Not sure about the concept of gradient vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I am not sure about the concept of gradient vectors, do i have to spit the function to  form to get the gradient vector?

Comment: The first thing to understand is why $f(x,y) = \ln \left|x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j} \right| = \ln (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$.  You then have to know how to take partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ of this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $|x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, so $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} \ln(x^2+y^2)$.

The gradient is the vector whose components are the partial derivatives of $f$.

For instance,

$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x}{|x\vec{i}+y\vec{j}|^2}
$

Can you see how to finish the problem?

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!